# Negating definition of limit as x approaches infinity of a function

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, logic, epsilon-delta

**Question**

How do I negate the definition of limit as x approaches infinity of a function?

Comment: For any $\epsilon > 0,$ for any $N>0$ there exists $n_1,n_2> N$ such that $|f(n_1) - f(n_2)| > \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First case

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f (x)=L\in \Bbb R $$

the negation is
$$(\exists \epsilon>0) \; \;( \forall A <0)\;\;(\exists x\in \Bbb R) \;\;:$$
$$ x <A \; \land\; |f (x)-L|\ge \epsilon $$

> Second case

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}f (x)=+\infty $$

the negation is
$$(\exists B>0) \;\; (\forall A <0) \;\;(\exists x\in \Bbb R) \;\;:$$
$$x <A \;\;\land f (x)<B $$

The third for you.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $L\in \mathbb R$.

Then $L$ is said to be the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ goes to infinity if and only if:

$\forall \epsilon \in \mathbb R: [\epsilon \gt 0 \implies \exists m\in \mathbb R: \forall x\in \mathbb R: [m\lt x \implies |f(x)-L|\lt \epsilon]].$

And it is false that $L$ is the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to infinity if and only if:

$\exists \epsilon \in R: [\epsilon \gt 0 \land \forall m\in \mathbb R: \exists x\in \mathbb R: [m\lt x \land |f(x)-1| \ge \epsilon]].$